# QPixmap, how to make sure it is 'always on top'

Tags: c++, qwidget, qpixmap

For Widgets I can call 'raise' which keeps the widget on top of anything else, but this doesn't seem to work for any QPixmap's that are rendered.

How can I ensure that a QPixmap remains on top of anything else?

In my paintEvent function:

```
    QPainter objPainter(this);

    if ( strImage.isEmpty() != true ) {
        qint16 int16NudgeImageX = mpobjNode->int16GetAttr(clsXML::mscszAttrNudgeImageX)
              ,int16NudgeImageY = mpobjNode->int16GetAttr(clsXML::mscszAttrNudeImageY);
        QPixmap pmImage(":/" + strImage);
        QSize szImage = pmImage.size();
        QPoint ptImage(rctGeom.center().x() - (szImage.width() / 2) + int16NudgeImageX
                      ,rctGeom.center().y() - (szImage.height() / 2) + int16NudgeImageY);
        QRect rctImage(ptImage, szImage);
        objPainter.drawPixmap(rctImage, pmImage);
    }
```

Comment: Can I suggest a read of http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html  and in particular the part that says about "WindowStaysOnTop"

Comment: @UKMonkey, thank you, I don't see any mention of QPixmap though.

Comment: If you don't assign a parent (which I assume you haven't; else you've no need to put it top; just let your layout manager deal with it) to your pixmap, then it becomes a top level window; nothing special about it from any other window

Comment: @UKMonkey, I've looked at QPixmap and I don't see anyway to assign a parent either.

Comment: QPixmap is per definition never visible. It is for offscreen rendering. Where and how do you paint your pixmap? Do you render into a widget? This question does not make sense at the moment...

Comment: In my paintEvent I create the QPixmap and paint it using the drawPixmap function.  I will edit to include a snippet of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [QPixmap](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qpixmap.html#details) is not a widget (no parent, nor layout).

> The QPixmap class is an off-screen image representation that can be used as a paint device.

Use a QLabel for use with a parent (and layout)

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel(parent);
label->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

Comment: Even though I too would recommend using QLabel in most cases, this answer does not answer the question. The Question uses a QPainter inside a widgets paintEvent to piant the pixmap. I see that this answer was accepted but in my opinion this could confuse future readers. Maybe you can add a short paragraph explaining why using QLabel is better than using the paintEvent in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that your QPixmap is painted on top of everything else inside your widget, simply paint it last.
Keep in mind that other widgets may be painted above your widget.